# Update text area with Ajax in Rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

This snippet is from my admin. I have a description field next to an image, and a demo of how'd that look below it.

Right now it works after a page refresh but i'd like it to work asynchronously using AJAX, so as the user types it updates the demo below the textarea.[image]

```
#This is where you update the field
<tr><th>Description</th><td><%= f.text_area(:description) %></td></tr>

    <tr><th>Demo</th>
      <td>
      <% if @org.images.present?  %>
          <table border="0">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <%= featured_image_tag(@org, :type => 'organization')  %>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;">
            <span class="font-avebook"><%= @org.description  %>  </span><br> 
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
          <% else   %>    
        You need to assoicate an image first before seeing the demo!
      <% end  %>    
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just to verify, the image is already loaded at this point? In other words, we're not handling the image with AJAX..

Comment: Exactly! The image is loaded first, on another page

Comment: If you just want to get the demo effect then the answer below should be a good fit. If you want to save it, then yeah just add ajax. Do you want an AJAX example? :).

Comment: I made an error below, I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text to appear directly below at the same time as you're writing you need to use a [jQuery Keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event to submit the data. However, submitting the data after each keyup is not the best idea. If you want to get that effect, why don't you just do the whole thing with jQuery without actually saving the data. You can append the contents of the input to the element beside the image after each keyup. I've made a little demo below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="copy_text">
  <div id="mirror_paragraph"></div>
<script>
    $("#copy_text").keyup(function () {
      var txt = $("#copy_text").val();
      $("#mirror_paragraph").html(txt);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Adapted to your code:

```
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <td><%= f.text_area(:description), :id => "copy_text" %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Demo</th>
  <td>
    <% if @org.images.present? %>
        <table border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= featured_image_tag(@org, :type => 'organization') %>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;">
              <span class="font-avebook" id="mirror_paragraph"><%= @org.description %>  </span><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    <% else %>
        You need to assoicate an image first before seeing the demo!
    <% end %>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
    $("#copy_text").keyup(function () {
      var txt = $("#copy_text").val();
      $("#mirror_paragraph").html(txt);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  getting a some compiling errors.  Worked through the first, how would i pass id without breaking it? <%= @org.description, :id => 'mirror_paragraph' %>

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake - sorry. I updated it. I should have added the handle mirror_paragraph to the parent span element, not the rails element.

Comment: you're the man, or woman ;-).  I already had a class on both those from doing some other stuff in the iterim so  I just applied it to that, and BOOM!

Comment: Also, great point, if I had made this with AJAX it would of been updated on the front too, what a brain fart!!!

Comment: Thanks. I make brain farts all the time. Long coding hours is what does it ;).